# Best choice among view, function and stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-view, sql-function

If I want to write a line of code just like below

```
SELECT EmpName 
FROM TblEmployee 
WHERE EmpID = 101
```

Input is fixed.

Which is the best choice among view, function and stored procedure and why?

There is no need of anything of that but I am questioned in an interview. So, I want to know.

Could some one help me?

Comment: It entirely depends on what you're using it for (and, I guess, whether empIDs are unique - you would assume they are but you don't really know). I'm going to guess the answer was a (scalar) function, for use in a select/where statement?

Comment: Ideally, look at MSDN's pages for these differences, too. [CREATE FUNCTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) and [CREATE VIEW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)
I think you will find their opening statements between the two objects very helpful.

Comment: My guess is that the point of the question was not for you to tell what the best one is, but to see if you understand and are able to explain the differences / use cases for a view, procedure and a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer stored procedure for your need because .

**1)**
**Reduced server/client network traffic**
The commands in a procedure are executed as a single batch of code. This can significantly reduce network traffic between the server and client because only the call to execute the procedure is sent across the network. Without the code encapsulation provided by a procedure, every individual line of code would have to cross the network.

**Stronger security**
Multiple users and client programs can perform operations on underlying database objects through a procedure, even if the users and programs do not have direct permissions on those underlying objects. The procedure controls what processes and activities are performed and protects the underlying database objects. This eliminates the requirement to grant permissions at the individual object level and simplifies the security layers.

**2)** The performance of function is slow when compared to sp.

**Note:** if you have a single select statement as mentioned you better to **use scalar function** or a **simple view**.

Comment: `The performance of function is slow when compared to sp` citation needed (especially for a function that would be as simple as this).

Comment: Plus, Tabular and Scalar Functions have entirely different use cases than a simple View. I would also suggest how Views are easily encapsulated in a synonym for added security.

Whereas a View is essentially an independent query, a scalar Function can be fired off for every row in a select statement (not saying the OP should haphazardly do so). In other words, their usage is distinctly different.